# how can i change error's messages in spring?

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm doing the step by step web app in spring described in here http://docs.spring.io/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

       <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
         <property name="basename" value="messages"/>
       </bean>

       <!-- Scans the classpath of this application for @Components to deploy as beans -->
       <context:component-scan base-package="com.companyname.springapp.web" />

       <!-- Configures the @Controller programming model -->
       <mvc:annotation-driven/>

       <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
         <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"></property>
         <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"></property>
         <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>        
       </bean>
</beans>

<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/views/include.jsp" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<html>
<head>
  <title><fmt:message key="title"/></title>
  <style>
    .error { color: red; }
  </style>  
</head>
<body>
<h1><fmt:message key="priceincrease.heading"/></h1>
<form:form method="post" commandName="priceIncrease">
  <table width="95%" bgcolor="f8f8ff" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
    <tr>
      <td align="right" width="20%">Increase (%):</td>
        <td width="20%">
          <form:input path="percentage"/>
        </td>
        <td width="60%">
          <form:errors path="percentage" cssClass="error"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Execute">
</form:form>
<a href="<c:url value="hello.htm"/>">Home</a>
</body>
</html>

package com.companyname.springapp.service;

import javax.validation.constraints.Max;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

public class PriceIncrease {

    /** Logger for this class and subclasses */
    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    @Min(0)
    @Max(50)
    private int percentage;

    public void setPercentage(int i) {
        percentage = i;
        logger.info("Percentage set to " + i);
    }

    public int getPercentage() {
        return percentage;
    }
}

package com.companyname.springapp.web;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

import com.companyname.springapp.service.PriceIncrease;
import com.companyname.springapp.service.ProductManager;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/priceincrease.htm")
public class PriceIncreaseFormController {

    /** Logger for this class and subclasses */
    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    @Autowired
    private ProductManager productManager;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String onSubmit(@Valid PriceIncrease priceIncrease, BindingResult result)
    {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "priceincrease";
        }

        int increase = priceIncrease.getPercentage();
        logger.info("Increasing prices by " + increase + "%.");

        productManager.increasePrice(increase);

        return "redirect:/hello.htm";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    protected PriceIncrease formBackingObject(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {
        PriceIncrease priceIncrease = new PriceIncrease();
        priceIncrease.setPercentage(15);
        return priceIncrease;
    }

    public void setProductManager(ProductManager productManager) {
        this.productManager = productManager;
    }

    public ProductManager getProductManager() {
        return productManager;
    }
}

title=SpringApp
heading=Hello :: SpringApp
greeting=Greetings, it is now
priceincrease.heading=Price Increase :: SpringApp
error.not-specified=Percentage not specified!!!
error.too-low=You have to specify a percentage higher than {0}!
error.too-high=Don''t be greedy - you can''t raise prices by more than {0}%!
required=Entry required.
typeMismatch=Invalid data.
typeMismatch.percentage=That is not a number!!!
```

The problem is I not getting the messages I've defined e.g when I insert 65 in the percentaje field I'm not getting the following message: Don''t be greedy - you can''t raise prices by more than {0}%!. Instead of this I'm getting the default message.
I've deleted the code asociated to the autowired annotation just to make the post shorter.
You must know the application works fine, the problems are in the returned messages.

How can I show the messages that I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post explains in detail how to do validation in spring mvc. [Click Here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-jsr303-valid-example/)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to implement the [Validator](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#validator) here's a simple example...

```
public class PriceIncreaseValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports( Class<?> clazz ) {
        return PriceIncrease.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate( Object o, Errors e ) {            
        PriceIncrease priceIncrease = (PriceIncrease) o;
       if( priceIncrease.getPercentage() == 0 ) {
           e.rejectValue( "priceIncrease", "error.too-low");
       } else if( priceIncrease.getPercentage() >= 50 ) {
           e.rejectValue( "priceIncrease", "error.too-high");
       }

    }
}
```